# Widget queries even when there are no sidebars?

Tags: widgets, database

I'm trying to reduce my database queries. I don't have any sidebars or widgets set but I noticed the following query

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_pages' LIMIT 1
```

Similar queries happen for widget_calendar, widget_links, widget_tag_cloud, and widget_nav_menu.

5 database queries for no reason. How do I disable this?

remove_action('widgets_init') doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does unregistering them the also disable the database queries?

Goes in functions.php:

```
//Unregister all Default Widgets

function unregister_default_wp_widgets() {
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Pages');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Archives');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Links');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Meta');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Search');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Text');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Categories');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Posts');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Recent_Comments');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_RSS');
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);
```

Comment: Yep, this works!

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in a theme, it stops any related db queries from running.

```
function unregister_all_default_wp_widgets() {
   // list the default WordPress widgets here
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_all_default_wp_widgets', 1);
```